# Difference between `exec n<&0 < file` and `exec n<file` commands and some general questions regarding exec command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, while-loop, exec

As I am a newbie in shell scripting, `exec` command always confuses me and while exploring this topic with `while` loop had triggered following 4 questions:

1. What is the difference between the below syntax 1 and 2

   syntax 1:

   ```
   while read LINE
   do
   : # manipulate file here
   done < file
   ```

   syntax 2:

   ```
   exec n<&0 < file
    while read LINE
    do
      : # manipulate file here
    done
   exec 0<&n n<&-
   ```
2. Kindly elaborate the operation of `exec n<&0 < file` lucidly
3. Is this `exec n<&0 < file` command equivalent to `exec n<file` ? (if not then what's the difference between two?)
4. I had read some where that in *Bourne shell and older versions of ksh*, **a problem with the `while` loop is that it is executed in a subshell**. This means that any changes to the script environment,such as exporting variables and changing the current working directory, might not be present after the `while` loop completes.
   As an example, consider the following script:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   if [ -f “$1” ] ; then
    i=0
     while read LINE
     do
      i=`expr $i + 1`
     done < “$1”
    echo $i
   fi
   ```

This script tries to count the number of lines in the file specified to it as an argument.

On executing this script on the file

```
$ cat dirs.txt
/tmp
/usr/local
/opt/bin
/var
```

can produce the following incorrect result:
0

Although you are incrementing the value of $i using the command
i=`expr $i + 1`
when the while loop completes, the value of $i is not preserved.

In this case, you need to ***change a variable’s value inside the `while` loop and then use that value outside the loop.***

One way to solve this problem is to redirect STDIN prior to entering the loop and then restore STDIN after the loop completes.

The basic syntax is

`exec n<&0 < file
while read LINE
do
: # manipulate file here
done
exec 0<&n n<&-`

My question here is:

In *Bourne shell and older versions of ksh*,*ALTHOUGH `WHILE` LOOP IS EXECUTED IN SUBSHELL*, how this `exec` command here helps in retaining variable value even after `while` loop completion i.e. how does here `exec` command accomplishes the task ***change a variable’s value inside the `while` loop and then use that value outside the loop.***

Comment: Please limit yourself to one question per post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The difference should be nothing in modern shells (both should be [POSIX compatible](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_07)), with some caveats:

   - There are likely thousands of unique shell binaries in use, some of which are missing common features or simply buggy.
   - Only the first version will behave as expected in an interactive shell, since the shell will close as soon as standard input gets EOF, which will happen once it finishes reading `file`.
   - The `while` loop reads from FD 0 in both cases, making the `exec` pointless if the shell supports `<` redirection to `while` loops. To read from FD 9 you have to use `done <&9` (POSIX) or `read -u 9` (in Bash).
2. `exec` (in this case, see `help exec`/`man exec`) applies the [redirections](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Redirection) following it to the current shell, and they are applied left-to-right. For example, `exec 9<&0 < file` points FD 9 to where FD 0 (standard input) is currently pointing, effectively making FD 9 a "copy" of FD 0. After that `file` is sent to standard input (both FD 0 and 9).
3. Run a shell within a shell to see the difference between the two (commented to explain):

   ```
   $ echo foo > file
   $ exec "$SHELL"
   $ exec 9<&0 < file
   $ foo # The contents of the file is executed in the shell
   bash: foo: command not found
   $ exit # Because the end of file, equivalent to pressing Ctrl-d
   $ exec "$SHELL"
   $ exec 9< file # Nothing happens, simply sends file to FD 9
   ```
4. This is a common misconception about *nix shells: *[Variables declared in subshells (such as created by `while`) are not available to the parent shell.](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024)* This is by design, not a bug. Many other answers here and on [USE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) refer to this.

Answer (score 2):

So many questions... but all of them seem variants of the same one, so I'll go on...

`exec` without a command is used to do redirection in the current process. That is, it changes the files attached to different file descriptors (FD).

#### Question #1

I think it should be this way. In may system the `{}` are mandadory:

```
exec {n}<&0 < file
```

This line dups FD 0 (standard input) and stores the new FD into the `n` variable. Then it attaches `file` to the standard input.

```
while read LINE ; do ... done
```

This line reads lines into variable `LINE` from the standard input, that will be `file`.

```
exec 0<&n {n}<&-
```

And this line dups back the FD from `n` into 0 (the original standard input), that automatically closes `file` and then closes `n` (the dupped original stdin).

The other syntax:

```
while read LINE; do ... done < file
```

does the same, but in a less convoluted way.

#### Question #2

```
exec {n}<&0 < file
```

These are redirections, and they are executed left to right. The first one `n<&0` does a `dup(0)` (see `man dup`) and stores the result new FD in variable `n`. Then the `<file` does a `open("file"...)` and assigns it to the FD 0.

#### Question #3

No. `exec {n}<file` opens the file and assigns the new FD to variable `n`, leaving the standard input (FD 0) untouched.

#### Question #4

I don't know about older versions of ksh, but the usual problem is when doing a pipe.

```
grep whatever | while read LINE; do ... done
```

Then the `while` command is run in a subshell. The same is true if it is to the left of the pipe.

```
while read LINE ; do ... done | grep whatever
```

But for simple redirects there is no subshell:

```
while read LINE ; do ... done < aaa > bbb
```

#### Extra unnumbered question

About your example script, it works for me once I've changed the typographic quotes to normal double quotes ;-):

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ -f "$1" ] ; then
 i=0
  while read LINE
  do
   i=`expr $i + 1`
  done < "$1"
 echo $i
fi
```

For example, if the file is `test`:

```
$ ./test test
9
```

And about your latest question, the subshell is not created by `while` but by the pipe `|` or maybe in older versions of ksh, by the redirection `<`. What the `exec` trick does is to prevent that redirection so no subshell is created.

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer your questions out-of-order.

### Q #2

The command `exec n<&0 < file` is not valid syntax. Probably the `n` stands for "some arbitrary number".  That said, for example

```
exec 3<&0 < file
```

executes two redirections, in sequence: it duplicates/copies the standard input file descriptor, which is `0`, as file descriptor `3`. Next, it "redirects" file descriptor `0` to read from file `file`.

Later, the command

```
exec 0<&3 3<&-
```

first copies back the standard input file descriptor from the saved file descriptor `3`, redirecting standard input back to its previous source. Then it closes file descriptor `3`, which has served its purpose to backup the initial `stdin`.

### Q #1

Effectively, the two examples do the same: they temporarily redirect stdin within the scope of the `while` loop.

### Q #3

Nope: `exec 3<filename` opens file `filename` using file descriptor `3`. `exec 3<&0 <filename` I described in #2.

### Q #4

I guess those older shells mentioned effectively executed

```
while ...; do ... ; done < filename
```

as

```
cat filename | while ...
```

thereby executing the `while` loop in a subshell.

Doing the redirections beforehand with those laborious `exec` commands avoids the redirection of the `while` block, and thereby the implicit sub-shell.

However, I never heard of that weird behavior, and I guess you won't have to deal with it unless you're working with truly ancient shells.